# Long running requests blocks all subsequent requests

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

For some reason nginx is not accepting any new requests whenever a slow request is being handled. A simple test is to have a script with a `sleep()` and call the script from different browsers/devices.

The first request is accepted then the second waiting and only accepted once the first request is completed. Is there a way around this?

nginx.conf

```
user                                nobody nobody;
worker_processes                    1;
error_log                           /var/log/nginx-error.log notice;

events {
  worker_connections              1024;
}

http {
  include                         mime.types;
  default_type                    application/octet-stream;

  # General settings
  index                           index.html index.php;
  sendfile                        on;
  server_tokens                   off;
  client_max_body_size            10M;

  # TCP options
  tcp_nodelay                   on;
  tcp_nopush                    on;

  # NginxHttpGzipModule
  gzip                            on;
  gzip_buffers                    16 8k;
  gzip_comp_level                 5;
  gzip_disable                    "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";
  gzip_http_version               1.0;
  gzip_min_length                 0;
  gzip_proxied                    any;
  gzip_types                      text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml application/xml+rss;
  gzip_vary                       on;

  include /usr/local/nginx/sites/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: What is your worker connections set to and can you post your nginx config file?

Comment: Since I've got only 1 core I've set the worker_processes to 1, updated my post with my config.

Comment: It seems my problem was due to the php-fpm settings `pm.*`. The reason why the requests were not handled by nginx is because there were no php-fpm process idle to process the request. Technically, nginx accepted the request but was waiting for a free php-fpm process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems my problem was due to the php-fpm settings pm.*. The reason why the requests were not handled by nginx is because there were no php-fpm process idle to process the request. Technically, nginx accepted the request but was waiting for a free php-fpm process.